# iand with different kind parameters using new gfortran version { gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) }

Tags: fortran, gfortran, type-kinds

I am trying to compile the dtc upp but when i try to build NCEP libraries for upp i am taking that error below:

```
    intmath.f:207:14:
    
    207 | if(iand(i,i-1)/=0) then | 1 Error: Arguments of ‘iand’ have different kind type parameters at (1) intmath.f:172:14:
    
    172 | if(iand(i,i-1)/=0) then | 1 Error: Arguments of ‘iand’ have different kind type parameters at (1) make[1]: *** [makefile:108: ../../../../libg2_v3.1.0_4.a(intmath.o)] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wrf/WRF/downloads/NCEPlibs/exec_linux.gnu/src/g2/v3.1.0/src' make: *** [Makefile:38: upplibs] Error 2

An error occurred building the NCEP libraries
```

Note: I searched and i found that gfortran versions 8 and earlier had as an extension the ability to call iand with integers of different kind , whereas this option was removed in gfortran 9 . So, i tried to uninstall gfortran 9 that is downloaded by default and install gfortran 7. Unfortunately it didn't work...Only the last version is recognized ....   Any ideas???????

Comment: Need to see source code.  Presumably, `i` is not default integer kind and has a kind type parameter that differs from the kind type parameter `1` where `i` has a smaller decimal range.

Comment: Fix the kind of 1 or i in the expression is by far the best way to fix this

Comment: Re "Unfortunately it didn't work...", with Ubuntu20.04LTS, I could install gfortran-7/8/9/10 separately by typing "sudo apt install gfortran-8" (which installs the command "gfortran-8") and similar for other versions (no need to uninstall each). So they may be useful for comparing results...